# Can't resize HTML input using percentage

Tags: html, css

I can't resize my input box using percentage. I'm really having trouble with this because once I run the code other computer, it doesn't display right which is, it should actually depend on the size of its div.

Here's the code for input

```
.input_box{
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #F8F8FF;
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
}
```

And here's the code of the div where the input box is located

```
.div_input_box{
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `flex: 1;` or `flex-grow: 1;` to your input:

```css
/* QuickReset */ * {margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}

.div_input_box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background:#eee;
}

.input_box {
  flex-grow: 1;    /* Add this */
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #F8F8FF;
  margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div_input_box">
  <input class="input_box" type="text" placeholder="Your value here">
</div>
```

- MDN: [CSS Flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) (shorthand)
- MDN: [CSS Flex-Grow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow)

Comment: I know how flex: 1 works, but I don't know how flex grow works. Can you enlighten me about flex grow? And Can I actually resize my input box using percentage if I applied flex grow?

Comment: Oh my bad, I didn't saw the CSS Flex-Grow tag.

Comment: @Luci you could use i.e: `flex: 0 0 33.333%;` or try to play with the input's `min-width` or `max-width` - depending on what you need.